# Dynamic url.pageId in plugin.tx_seo config for own extension

Tags: slug, typo3-9.x, sitemap.xml

In my TYPO3 9 installation I'am working on a custom sitemap.xml for my own extension (Events). There I want to have a separate pageId / detail page for each entry.

As i understood in the config section of tx_seo I can only provide one specific pageId as detail page id - correct?

I tried this config:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
               veranstaltung {
                  provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                  config {
                     table = tx_ntevents_domain_model_veranstaltung
                     sortField = kursnummer
                     lastModifiedField = tstamp
                     recursive = 1
                     pid = 110
                     url {
                        pageId = # here different pages which can be found in tx_ntevents_domain_model_veranstaltung.seite1 #
                        fieldToParameterMap {
                          uid = nt_events_pi1[veranstaltung] # is this correct? #
                        }
                        additionalGetParameters {
                          nt_events_pi1.controller = Veranstaltung
                          nt_events_pi1.action = show
                        }
                    }
              ...
```

With this setup tx_seo finds all entries but does not

- provide a specific page id for each entry and
- does not generate the nice slug url

Here is the slug code from config.yaml

```
  NtEvents:
    type: Extbase
    extension: NtEvents
    plugin: Events
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{veranstaltung-url}'
        _controller: 'Veranstaltung::show'
        _arguments:
          veranstaltung-url: veranstaltung
    defaultController: 'Veranstaltung::list'
    aspects:
      veranstaltung-url:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_ntevents_domain_model_veranstaltung
        routeFieldName: slug
        routeValuePrefix: /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own DataProvider, in your case it would probably be easiest to copy the original "\TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider" into your own extension and rewrite it according to your wishes or adapt it accordingly.